# Enabling CORS on Apache for OpenCPU

Tags: r, opencpu

I was testing my first OpenCPU project, having the web test page in the same server than OpenCPU and the R package (an Ubuntu 14.04 server installed in a virtual machine inside Windows Server) it works fine, but I'll probably need the website to be in the Windows Server and OpenCPU (so R too) running in the virtual machine, so I tried the *seturl* function from OpenCPU to do that, but I got an error which says "that can be fixed enabling CORS in the server"

Looking for a solution I found http://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html In this article is told how to enable CORS in Apache, but what I couldn't find was what folder needs the permission to make OpenCPU remotely works.

This is how I call the package on virtual's machine server

`ocpu.seturl("http://virtualmachine_ipaddres/ocpu/library/PruebaR/R")`

I tried giving the permissions to the R folder and others but still not working. Any ideas?

Thank you for your help

Comment: OpenCPU has CORS enabled by default. What browser are you using and which error are you getting? Its probably not a CORS problem.

Comment: Hi @Jeroen!. Fails in Firefox and Chrome, error message by Firebug is: "Same origin policy doesn't allow to read remote resource in "http://virtualmachine_ipaddres/ocpu/library/PruebaR/R" This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS"

Trying to enter to the website from Windows Server browser (the one which contents the virtual machine with Ubuntu) works fine, only fails triyng to access from another computer in local network with "http://windows_server_ip_address/test.html" (test.html is the one which calls OpenCPU)

Thank you for your help

Comment: That is strange. Are you using a standard opencpu 1.4.5 installation? What do the response headers look like if you do a request in the [`/ocpu/test`](http://public.opencpu.org/ocpu/test/) page on your server?

Comment: Ok I could fix this, finally it was a Virtual Machine issue, I had to change VMWare Newtork Adapter and set Ubuntu's IP to static to set the virtual server in my local network. Fixed this I have another little issue now, OpenCPU makes this request after calling a R function `http://ubuntu_V_machine_iphttp//ubuntu_V_machine_ip/ocpu/tmp/x01db2799b1/R/.val/json` I think the cause is to put "http://" in seturl function parameter, but after removing it I got the follow error message: "Connection to OpenCPU failed: error undefined NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied" Thanks again

Comment: Have a look at the jsfiddle examples to see how to do it: http://jsfiddle.net/user/opencpu/fiddles/

Comment: Thank you @Jeroen! Finally I made it work but I had to comment this line in opencpu-0.4.js, in r_fun_ajax function: `//in case of cors we translate the relative path
      if(r_cors){
        //loc = r_path.protocol + "//" + r_path.host + loc;
      }`
Loc variable already contained full path, host and location, and in this line path was added again, returning a wrong location. Commenting that line I got the right location and my example started to work fine. Thanks again for your help